# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () when deploying an app in GoogleAppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am developing an App using google app engine and locally everything works fine, images and static files are loaded properly.

But after deploying the app an error raises on the browser console:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

It happens with both images and static files located in my project `static` folder.

I checked twice and paths are correct as there's no problem when debugging in localhost with `python main.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Locally works fine because Flask already exposes the static path.

From docs:

> Flask automatically adds a static view that takes a path relative to the flaskr/static directory and serves it

**So the problem it's on the app deploy.**

The mistake I was doing is to miswrite the handlers on the `app.yaml` file. I was writing a `/` on the `static_dir` value and AppEngine was not serving the folder properly.

The following code and comments point to some things that can cause a wrong implementation of the handlers, including the one already mentioned.

```
# 1. The handlers key not indented
handlers:
  # 2. The URL key indented and with leading -
  # 3. The URL value WITH a leading /
  - url: /static
  # 3. The static_dir key behind the url
  # 4. The static dir value WITHOUT the leading / 
    static_dir: static
```